# User reputation value shown in chat is not updated, right after its change

Tags: discussion, reputation, chat

I posted the following message into the chat: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/823794#823794 (my reputation was equal to **1032** at that time).

After that I started a bounty on the referenced request. Which of course decreased my reputation by the bounty amount (to **932**). However the chat still shows that my reputation is **1032**:

[image: Chat screenshot]

So does the chat profile page:

[image: Chat profile page]

Is this a bug or an expected behavior (because of cache)?

Comment: Caching. Hope you have heard of it.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I heard about it (actually I was updating my question to mention the cache, but my browser crashed), however I thought it was only applicable to cross network things (like User Flair).

Comment: Now, after my browser has restarted reputations are synchronized in both places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chat loads reputation when you load the chatroom (or someone enters), but it doesn't continuously poll for reputation changes, this is by-design - since it very rarely matters.

Comment: I see… And what about "Chat Profile" page. Does the same rule apply to it?

Comment: @Idolon - The profile is on a different page or AJAX loaded...those are loaded when viewed not cached *on the client* so much, but they aren't updated continuously, on the hour IIRC.